# How to map an absolute URI Path from "/xxx/some.file" to "/something/xxx/some.file" using .htaccesss

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, coldfusion, url-rewriting

thanks for your help; I'm new to all this URL mapping, however I believe this is a simple problem...

I'm migrating a ColdFusion application from GoDaddy (who recently dropped their ColdFusion support) to [CFDynamics](http://cfdynamics.com).

I have a URL for my new root: cfd123.cfdynamics.com/lbc this is my wwwroot directory where I've put the website.  (It's actually: D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\lbc.com\wwwroot but I don't think that matters)

The problem is that all the HTML URIs: href and src attributes, etc. within the site were written using absolute paths:   "/images/some.jpg", etc. and now I want them to map to "cfd123.cfdynamics.com/lbc/images/some.jpg".

I figure I need to map "/something" to "/lbc/something" everywhere it's referenced.  This seems like it should be simple, just map a leading "/" to "/lbc/" and I'm good to go.

So, I went to create an "Alias / /lbc/" sort of listing and put it in my .htaccess file.  Now I discover that Alias isn't allowed in .htaccess.  (I think if I had access to httpd.conf I could use an Alias there, but it's a shared hosting environment and I don't have that access.)

So, I thought I'd try rewriting rules (still in the .htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /lbc
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

To no avail.   So, I'm not finding that any of the obvious things work (and I'm not even sure I've done them correctly).   I don't see any debug mechanisms that are showing me anything (chrome just shows me the 404 errors one would expect when a file isn't found.)

And this is all new to me and starts getting pretty hairy pretty fast.   Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks, Steve

p.s. I can take care of the ColdFusion CFInclude directives by creating an Application.cfc file in the wwwroot directory containing the code below, but that doesn't do anything for the various HTML links throughout the page.

```
<cfset this.name = "AbsoluteReference"/>
<cfset this.mappings = structNew() />
<cfset this.mappings["/"] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())/>
```

Comment: This is not a programming question. It'd probably be a better fit on [SF].  Although you're approaching it wrong anyway. Stop using absolute paths - if you use `./images` then you don't have this problem - and you wont need to switch again when you get your proper domain setup (the cfd123 thing is likely to be just a temporary one, not your site's final resting place).

Comment: Sorry if Server Fault is a better place, I'll keep that in mind.

I agree about absolute paths... but these are the cards I'm dealt and modding them all to relative paths is ugly.

And, I'm new to this hosting provider and how they work.  Turns out they parse the Host Headers to route traffic to the proper webroot; so, once I'd kicked over the DNS entries on my domain to point to them instead of testing it directly with the cfd123 domain (which isn't temporary, it's just not going to be ever used) then everything works as expected.  So, I'm resolved without any further work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your running a windows server at CFDynamics I can tell from this

I have a URL for my new root: cfd123.cfdynamics.com/lbc this is my wwwroot directory where I've put the website. (It's actually: **D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\lbc.com\wwwroot** but I don't think that matters)

This is a windows structure "D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\lbc.com\wwwroot" so .htaccess will not work for URL rewrites, since your on a shared environment you will not be able to do what you need to. These changes would have to be made in IIS and that's not an option. If you have Dreamweaver you can do a mass find replace for /images/ and replace with /ibc/images/ and for link do href="/ replace with href="/ibc/.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks John.  I know and understand what you're saying about a Windows server.  Their support told me that they support .htaccess.  With a little more digging I found that they do this through IIRF (http://iirf.codeplex.com/) A rewrite filter plug-in for IIS.

Yes, modifying all the code throughout the site is a possibility, however I was hoping to avoid it since everything worked beautifully and it's always possible to introduce errors, miss things, etc.   It seemed easier to do rewriting, etc.